# How do I check if member have role

Tags: bots, discord, discord.py

How do I check if the `message.author` has `admin` role?

Or is there a way I can check if a member have a higher role than another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `discord.utils.get` to get a role if it exists in the list of a `Member`s roles.

```
from discord.utils import get

if get(member.roles, name="admin"):
    # has role
else:
    # does not have role
```

To determine position in the hierarchy, you can compare the highest roles of the `Member`s

```
if member1.top_role > member2.top_role:
    # member 1 is higher than member 2
```

Comment: your my best developer helper i really appreciate a help from a good and experienced developer like you :)

Answer (score 1):

## To get role(s) of user

- You can either comparing with the role's name

  `message.member.roles` is a collection. It mean you just look for the role directly in the collection. Like this:

  `if(message.member.roles.find(r => r.name === "Admin") || message.member.roles.find(r => rname === "AnotherRole"))`
- Or you can check directly if a member have certain role with the `Map.has` method. This will check for keys, not values, so you'll have to use the roles' ids instead.

  `message.member.roles.has(adminRole.id)`

  `message.member.roles.has(modRole.id)`

## To compare a role to another

You can simply use this kind of code (has described in the official documentation)

```
if(role_of_author > role_of_user_to_be_banned)
```

But take care that one user can have multiple roles, so adapt this condition based on your use case.

---

You can refer to the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#role) for more information.

Comment: thank you sir, _but how do i check if the member hes trying to ban has a certain role is higher than his role like if a admin is trying to ban a highadmin_ then the bot will say "**you can't ban a member who has a role higher than you**"

Comment: can u tell me deeply of how do i check of the member to be banned has a certian role

Comment: @racoon how do i check if the member writting the  command has a certian role??

Comment: check it like if the user writting the message has admin role the bot sends your admin, if the member wirtting the command has member the bot sends your member

Comment: @racoon didn't tried anything because i don't even know what is the code to write

Comment: Maybe you can start by creating a simple bot. You will try to figure how to kick a bit after. Check this article: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-create-a-discord-bot-under-15-minutes-fb2fd0083844

Comment: I have made **ban, help, kick, mute** games like **rps and 8ball** added a command for **on member join and on member remove** and change the bots presence to **listening and dnd** (do not disturb), i just can't fond the command for check the users role and the member hes targeting 
 [My own discord server](https://discord.gg/bwfQ5Gk) i have a my own bot here join (sorry for advertising) remove the invite link if any body things its not right

Comment: also i am using **Discord.py-Rewrite** and the command u gave is not working at all